# Why does another DocumentRoot works but the one defined in /etc/apache2/httpd.con does not?

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf

The apache server was pre-installed with Lion. The problem is that default DocumentRoot in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf is "/Library/Webserver/Documents", but it turns out to point to another directory ,which is "/usr/htdocs" ,when I visit my page, say ,localhost/demo.php !

I can't figure out why this happens,and I am sure the httpd.conf under /etc/apache2/ is the exact configure file which apache reads when it runs.

Part of the result when I run httpd -V is as follow:

```
     Server compiled with....
     -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
     -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
     -D APR_HAS_MMAP
     -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
     -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
     -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
     -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
     -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
     -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
     -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
     -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
     -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
     -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
     -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
     -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
     -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
     -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
     -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

I will be so gratefull for any reply!Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check what `DocumentRoot` is defined in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 0):

Your http dump shows you your answer. The httpd root is set to usr. You will need to open your http conf file and edit it to change where it points. Also you may have an .htaccess file in usr that directs all traffic to htdocs, or it may be set in the apache http conf. Check the official apache website for more info.